# Cannot connect to OData v4 service with Excel Power Query: invalid metadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, powerquery

The April 2015 version of the Excel Power Query advertises OData v4 compatibility. However, when I try to connect to my OData v4 service written with Web API (`Microsoft.Data.OData.5.6.0`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.5.1`, `Microsoft.OData.Core.6.10.0`), I'm getting a

> DataSource.Error: OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid.

Am I the only one? Is there a way to debug this?

Here's the metadata document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="MyCompany.Api.OData" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityType Name="Position" OpenType="true">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="PositionId" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="StartDate" Type="Edm.Date" />
        <Property Name="Status" Type="MyCompany.Positions.ValidationStatus" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="InstrumentTypeId" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Feed">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Name" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="Deliveries" Type="Collection(MyCompany.Api.OData.Delivery)" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Delivery">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ReferenceDate" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ReferenceDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="Positions" Type="Collection(MyCompany.Api.OData.Position)" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="MyCompany.Positions" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EnumType Name="ValidationStatus">
        <Member Name="Invalid" Value="0" />
        <Member Name="Valid" Value="1" />
        <Member Name="Expired" Value="2" />
      </EnumType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container">
        <EntitySet Name="Positions" EntityType="MyCompany.Api.OData.Position" />
        <EntitySet Name="Feeds" EntityType="MyCompany.Api.OData.Feed">
          <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Deliveries" Target="Deliveries" />
        </EntitySet>
        <EntitySet Name="Deliveries" EntityType="MyCompany.Api.OData.Delivery">
          <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Positions" Target="Positions" />
        </EntitySet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

**EDIT**

After enabling diagnostics in the Power Query ribbon under Options, I see the following warnings:

```
DataMashup.Trace Warning: 24579 : {"Start":"2015-05-26T18:26:53.5539195Z","Action":"Engine/IO/OData/Create","ServiceUri":"http://localhost:54026/.../odata/v4","RequestUrl":"http://localhost:54026/.../odata/v4","RequestHeaders":"null","Exception":"Exception:\r\nExceptionType: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ValueException, Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nMessage: [DataSource.Error] OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.EdmModelProcessorBase`1.Build()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataEnvironment.Create(ServiceDocumentWrapper serviceDoc, Uri metadataUri, Value headers, String resourceKind, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, IEngineHost host, ODataSettings settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings, Boolean useCachedCredentials)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataResponse.Create(Uri requestUri, HttpResponseData responseData, String resourceKind, Value headers, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, IEngineHost host, ODataSettings settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.GetFeed(String resourceKind, TextValue serviceUriValue, TextValue uriValue, Value headers, IEngineHost host, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, ODataSettingsBase settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings, Boolean useCachedCredentials)\r\n\r\nInnerException\r\nException:\r\nExceptionType: System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\r\nMessage: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataTypeServices.GetTypeValueFromEdm(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetTypeValue(IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreateTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreatePropertyTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmProperty property)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.CreateRecordTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmStructuredType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreateTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.ProcessTypes()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.EdmModelProcessorBase`1.Build()\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n","ProductVersion":"2.22.4007.242 (Release-V2-Public)","ActivityId":"22edde60-34b3-49eb-8dda-75507d00be29","Process":"Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40","Pid":6244,"Tid":1,"Duration":"00:00:00.2893059"}
DataMashup.Trace Warning: 24579 : {"Start":"2015-05-26T18:26:53.8596010Z","Action":"SimpleDocumentEvaluator/BeginGetResult<IPreviewValueSource>/callback","Exception":"Exception:\r\nExceptionType: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ValueException, Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nMessage: [DataSource.Error] OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.EvaluationResult2`1.get_Result()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SimpleDocumentEvaluator.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginGetResult>b__0(EvaluationResult2`1 result)\r\n\r\nInnerException\r\nException:\r\nExceptionType: System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\r\nMessage: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataTypeServices.GetTypeValueFromEdm(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetTypeValue(IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreateTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreatePropertyTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmProperty property)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.CreateRecordTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmStructuredType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.GetOrCreateTypeValue(Stack`1 processingTypes, IEdmType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.EdmModelProcessor.ProcessTypes()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.EdmModelProcessorBase`1.Build()\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n","ProductVersion":"2.22.4007.242 (Release-V2-Public)","ActivityId":"22edde60-34b3-49eb-8dda-75507d00be29","Process":"Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40","Pid":6244,"Tid":1,"Duration":"00:00:00.0040547"}
DataMashup.Trace Warning: 24579 : {"Start":"2015-05-26T18:26:53.2420994Z","Action":"SimpleDocumentEvaluator/BeginGetResult<IValue>","Exception":"Exception:\r\nExceptionType: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ValueException, Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nMessage: [DataSource.Error] OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid.\r\nStackTrace:\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.EdmModelProcessorBase`1.Build()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataEnvironment.Create(ServiceDocumentWrapper serviceDoc, Uri metadataUri, Value headers, String resourceKind, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, IEngineHost host, ODataSettings settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings, Boolean useCachedCredentials)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataResponse.Create(Uri requestUri, HttpResponseData responseData, String resourceKind, Value headers, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, IEngineHost host, ODataSettings settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.GetFeed(String resourceKind, TextValue serviceUriValue, TextValue uriValue, Value headers, IEngineHost host, ResourceCredentialCollection credentials, ODataSettingsBase settings, ODataUserSettings userSettings, Boolean useCachedCredentials)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.GetFeed(String resourceKind, TextValue serviceUri, Value headers, Value options, IEngineHost host, Boolean isPrivileged)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.ODataModule.FeedFunctionValue.TypedInvoke(TextValue serviceUri, Value headers, Value options)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue3`4.Invoke(Value arg0, Value arg1, Value arg2)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue3`4.Invoke(Value arg0)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.FunctionValue.MetaTypeFunctionValue.Invoke(Value arg0)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.SerializationApplyingModule.SerializableFunctionValue.Invoke(Value arg0)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FunctionInvocationExpression1.Execute(Value frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugExpression.Execute(Value frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FunctionInvocationExpression2.Execute(Value frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.DebugExpression.Execute(Value frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RuntimeFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordExpression.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordExpression.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.RecordValue.get_Item(String field)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FieldAccessExpression.Execute(Value frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RuntimeFunctionValue1.Invoke(Value arg0)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordExpression.RuntimeRecordValue.Force(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.RecordExpression.RuntimeRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.RecordValue.get_Item(Value key)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.Library.Linker.BindFunctionValue.TypedInvoke(RecordValue environment, Value section, TextValue name)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.NativeFunctionValue3`4.Invoke(Value arg0, Value arg1, Value arg2)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.FunctionValue.Invoke(Value[] args)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ExpressionInvocationExpression.Execute(MembersFrame0& frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionValue0.Invoke()\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ListExpression.RuntimeListValue.Force(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ListExpression.RuntimeListValue.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ListValue.get_Item(Value key)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.Library.List.ElementWithListCheckFunctionValue.Invoke(Value collection, Value key)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.FunctionInvocationExpression2.Execute(MembersFrame1& frame)\r\n   at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.MembersFunctionV","ProductVersion":"2.22.4007.242 (Release-V2-Public)","ActivityId":"22edde60-34b3-49eb-8dda-75507d00be29","Process":"Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40","Pid":6244,"Tid":1,"Duration":"00:00:00.6215902"}
```

Unfortunately, I don't see any errors that are specific to our OData API.

Answer (score 2):

Could you share the service url with us? If it's public and doesn't have sensitive data :). Can you also try loading the metadata document in the browser, does it load correctly without errors?
If it works in the browser, then we will need a service url to repro the problem or fiddler traces.

Thanks,
Hadeel

Comment: Unfortunately, it is non-public and contains sensitive data to some extent. But it does load in the browser. I'll update my question to contain the stripped metadata xml (I hope, I don't break anything by removing the sensitive parts... :)

Comment: I can't really tell just from the metadata, it could be that parsing it in OData failed. So how about you turn on tracing, look at the logs and tell me if you see any OData specific errors in there, or share the logs privately with me?

Comment: To enable tracing: Power Query ribbon -> Options -> Enable Power Query tracing checkbox

Comment: I've turned on tracing, and I see `ValueException`s with two different stack traces, one with an inner `InvalidOperationException` at `at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataTypeServices.GetTypeValueFromEdm(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)`. The second one has no inner exception and happens at `Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.EdmModelProcessorBase`1.Build()`. So basically, I'm still lost. How can I share the log with you privately? Wild guessing: is Power Query supporting enums?

Comment: No no that's good, we are getting to the bottom of it now, can you copy the sections in the trace that has value exceptions here?

Comment: I've appended the tracing logs to the question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It seems that ODataLibrary is unable to parse your metadata document. Could you use the OData helper: http://services.odata.org/validation/# to validate your service?

Comment: I already did. See my comment at the end of lukehellrunner's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do more investigation without debugging the service myself. If you could click on the Feedback button in PQ then send a frown, attach a debuggable copy of your service (without any sensitive data), I might be able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the OData Validator service which has recently been updated to support OData v4:

http://services.odata.org/validation/#

In fact it shows one error for the metadata document you provided, but this may or may not be the problem that lets PowerQuery fail.
Today I tested the new PowerQuery version with my own OData (v4) service which worked fine, but I`m using ODataLib / Microsoft.OData.Core directly without the Web API integration.

Comment: The validation yields one error: _Structured Types are composed of zero or more structural properties (represented as edm:Property elements) and navigation properties (represented as edm:NavigationProperty elements)_. Not sure what this is referring to.